# How to avoid bitmaps while drawing on picture boxes

Tags: c#, bitmap

I am writing a C# program to display a audio signal and I was succeeded as follow,

1. I put the picturebox on a scroll panel on my form.
2. Sampled the PCM data and made a bitmap and placed it on the picture box.

But recently I found that the size of the bitmap is limited in C# (2^16 pixels). Therefore, it is impossible to display long audio files using bitmap object.

I am looking for a alternative solution for this matter (Drawing directly to picture box). Can anybody please help me ?

Comment: Capture the picturebox.paint event, and draw using the `Graphics` object. You'd need to create several off-screen `Bitmap`s.

Comment: The size of a control is limited to 2^16.  So don't use a PictureBox.  Set the panel's AutoScrollMinSize property and implement its Paint event.  Use AutoScrollPosition to figure out where to index the data.  Call Invalidate() in its Scroll event.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own control instead of using a `PictureBox`. Derive from `Control` for example and override the `OnPaintXXX` events.

You could then pass the sample information to the control and have it repaint itself. To speed things up, you might also do the painting in chunks. By that I mean: divide the area to be painted into a number of  rectangles, paint all the rectangles independently (threads?) into bitmaps and paint the bitmaps to the respective locations.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure where you got that information. From MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx

> The maximum height and width of an image is 2^16 pixels at 32 bits per channel * 4 channels. The maximum size of a BitmapSource is 2^32 bytes (64 gigabytes) and the maximum image size is four gigapixels. The minimum image size is 1x1.

I'm suspecting that you read "Maximum Width and Height" as "Maximum Size" which it isn't. It's the maximum number of pixels along one direction.